# Vyper - Why is my first memory variable placed with an offset of 0x40 (64 bytes) instead of 0x20 (32 bytes) or even 0x00 (no offset)?

Tags: evm, opcode, vyper

I have a vyper contract, as such:

```py
@external
def add_two(my_number: uint256) -> uint256:
    two: uint256 = 123456
    return my_number + two
```

When you compile this (with `0.3.6`), a piece of the opcode output that looks like so:

```
PUSH3 0x1E240 
PUSH1 0x40 
MSTORE
```

`0x1E240` is the hex for `123456`, and `0x40` will be our offset in memory when we call `MSTORE`, so this is the section of the opcodes responsible for the `two: uint256 = 123456` piece of the vyper, and storing that value to memory.

My question though, is why didn't vyper use `PUSH 0x20` instead of `0x40`? I checked the rest of the code, and the first 32 bytes of memory is **never** written to with `MSTORE` or read from with `MLOAD`.

So why does vyper add an extra 32 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

Vyper reserves the first two slots in memory for mainly keccak operations.

Just an implementation detail.